# Storing Phonegap geolocation coordinates in the database

Tags: cordova, geolocation

I am trying to store the following geolocation info into a SQL Server database and am unable to find information on the datatype and the width of each column. Any help is appreciated

`Latitude
Longitude
Altitude
Accuracy
AltitudeAccuracy
Heading
Speed`

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at www.phonegap.com and i found the following information:

Properties

latitude: Latitude in decimal degrees. (Number)

longitude: Longitude in decimal degrees. (Number)

altitude: Height of the position in meters above the ellipsoid. (Number)

accuracy: Accuracy level of the latitude and longitude coordinates in meters. (Number)

altitudeAccuracy: Accuracy level of the altitude coordinate in meters. (Number)

heading: Direction of travel, specified in degrees counting clockwise relative to the true north. (Number)

speed: Current ground speed of the device, specified in meters per second. (Number)